# Select Laravel Inserindo Proximo Registro Sozinho

Tags: php, laravel, select, html-select, laravel-blade

Boa noite, tenho um projeto em laravel e estou com  a seguinte dificuldade:

tenho um controller que recupera os dados do meu banco, tem uma variável que recebe string e essa string converto para array

```html
public function edit($id)
{
    $dados=Treinodet::find($id);
    $obj= Treino::find($dados->treino_id);
    $string = $dados->especificidade;
    $exer  = explode(',', $string);
            
    $exercs= DB::select("select *from lista where id != 0 and idtipo in(8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)");
    return view('treino.exercad',compact('obj','exercs','dados','exer'));
}
```

jogo esses dados para a view comparo se tem algum dado da string que condiz com 
a lista se tiver eu dou o selected até ai tudo certo funciona tudo 100%.
Mas quando altero qualquer outro dado nesse formulário esse select sempre insere o proximo item na lista sem eu fazer nada.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-8">
  <label>Exercicio</label>
  <select name="especificidade[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control select-search">
    {{$i=0}}
    @foreach($exercs as $item)
      <option value="{{ $item->descricao }}" @if(isset($exer[$i]) == $item->descricao) selected @else @endif>{{ $item->descricao }}</option>
    {{$i++}}
    @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

Salva os dados

```html
 public function exercad(request $request)
    {
        $param = $request->all();
        $obj= Treinodet::find($param['id']);
        if(empty($obj)){
            $exer = $param['especificidade'];
            $stringArrayF="";
            foreach ($exer as $stringArray)
            {
              $stringArrayF = $stringArray.', '.$stringArrayF;
            }
            $param['especificidade']= $stringArrayF;
    
            $obj = Treinodet::create($param);
        }
        else{
            $exer = $param['especificidade'];
            $stringArrayF="";
            foreach ($exer as $stringArray)
            {
              $stringArrayF = $stringArray.', '.$stringArrayF;
            }
            $param['especificidade']= $stringArrayF;
    
            $obj->update($param);

        }
        
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Cadastro Criado com sucesso');

    }
```

como eu faço para que isso não ocorra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando recuperava os dados do banco, a `String` que estava separada por vírgula eu utilizava o comando:

`explode(',', $string);`

Fazendo com que a String se separasse mas com tudo sempre ficava uma `,` no final restante.

para a solução disso tive que fazer um laço removendo `,` e espaços.

```
$new_arr  = explode(',', $string);
    foreach($new_arr as $value)
    {
        if($value=="," || $value==" ")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            $exer[]=$value;
        }     
    }
```

Realizando isso o erro parou de ocorrer.

Comment: Há outras maneiras de fazer isso, como o array_pop que irá retirar o ultimo elemento do array (sendo possível salvar ele em uma variável, btw)

Answer (score 3):

O interessante seria você postar seu controller todo. Para poder analisar como está funcionando.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8">
<label>Exercicio</label>
<select name="especificidade[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control select-search">
    @foreach($exercs as $i => $item)
        <option value="{{ $item->descricao }}" {{ (isset($exer[$i]) == $item->descricao) ? 'selected': '' }}>{{ $item->descricao }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Vê se isso vai resolver seu problema.

Cara, não faço ideia do que pode estar ocorrendo com seu código. Vou colocar um exemplo abaixo de como eu faço com múltiplos selects.

Meu controller:

```
public function adicionarAdicional(Request $request, Adicional $adi)
{

$auth = Session::get('auth');

if (!$auth) {
    return Redirect::to('/login')->withErrors(['Acesso negado.']);
} else {

    $request->all();

    $adicionais = $request->dt_adicional;

    $this->validate($request, [
        'dt_adicional.*' => [new Data]
    ]);

    $id_servidor = Session::get('id_servidor');

    foreach ($adicionais as $i => $adicional) {

        $dt_adicional = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $adicional)->format('Y-m-d');

        $adici = $adi::create(array(
            'id_servidor' => $id_servidor,
            'dt_adicional' => $dt_adicional,
        ));
    }
}
}
```

E abaixo minha view:

```
@foreach ($datas as $i=>$data)
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{$data}}" id="dt_adicional{{$i}}" name="dt_adicional[]">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="dt_adicional{{$i}}">
                {{$data}}
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="tempo{{$i}}" style="display:none">

        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Espero que com isso você consiga descobrir algo.

Comment: irei testar e te respondo, desde já agradeço pela moral

Comment: testei aqui e continua com o mesmo problema

Comment: Me mostra o Controller todo. Para poder analisar melhor.

Comment: ta ai o controller todo douglas

Comment: @TulioVieira, esse controller que você colocou é o que retorna para a view. Eu quero o Controller que salva os dados no banco. Pq é nessa parte que está dando o erro correto ? Ou entendi errado ?

Comment: está ai o a função que salva os dados @douglas pjuizfora

Comment: @TulioVieira, coloquei um caso parecido de múltiplos selects. Mas realmente não faço ideia do que está acontecendo.